# eclipse android application syntax error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i just started to use eclipse, and im trying to do my first android application. But apparently something is wrong with my syntax error , and i dont know how can i fix it or where did i do wrongly. so i hope someone here can help me. Thanks :) pardon me for my bad english.

Those underlined in red are errors but i dont know how can i fix them.

## starts below here

Here is my .java

```
public class Category extends Activity { <---(**this sign is underlined in red**)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            };
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }                         ^
              (**this sign is underlined in red**)

};
```

Comment: `import android.app.Activity;` in your `Activity`

Comment: press Ctrl+Shift+O for auto-import in Eclipse

Comment: i edited the post by abit . please help me to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're trying to initialize your button listener in another button listener. That's wrong.

### Corrected:

```
 Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

 switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
        startActivity(intent);

   };
  });

  Button switchButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

  switchButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    };
});
```

Comment: okay thanks. but now i still got some small errors with 

--->public class Category extends Activity { <---(this sign is still underlined.)
--->return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); (the (I) in Item is underlined)

Comment: @EclipseNoob What is that?